# CSS - Change parent div background-color on input check

Tags: html, css

```css
    .chk-circle {
     width: 8px;
     height: 8px;
     background: #afb0b5;
     border-radius: 100%;
     position: relative;
     float: left;
     margin-top: 4px;
     margin-right: 8px;
    }
    
    .chk-circle label {
     display: block;
     width: 4px;
     height: 4px;
     border-radius: 100px;
     cursor: pointer;
     position: absolute;
     top: 2px;
     left: 2px;
     z-index: 1;
     background: #fff;
    }
    
    .chk-hide {
      visibility: hidden;
    }

    .chk-circle input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
     background: #63a70a;
    }
```

```html
   <div class="chk-circle">
      <input class="chk-hide" type="checkbox" id="chk1"/>
   <label for="chk1"></label>
   </div>
```

Which produces the following:

[image]

What I want to do is have the outer circle turn green when the input is checked, I have tried the following but the reverse happens:

[image]

Comment: try adding color to the border?

Comment: Don‘t misuse `label` like that. For the examples you have shown, the label elements should contain the text that is written next to the checkboxes.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

Apply with `border` property :

***Updated***

I was added the `i` for bullet creation.If you need increase the bullet size increase the `width & height` of `I` tag.And also added text in label. Both condition are working

```
.chk-circle input[type=checkbox]:checked + i {
      top:0;
      left:0;
      border:2px solid green;
    }
```

```css
.chk-circle > i {
  position:relative;
  float:left;
    display: block;
    width: 6px;
    height: 6px;
  margin-top:5px ;
    border-radius: 100px;
    cursor: pointer;
     z-index: 1;
  border:3px solid #ddd;
    background: #fff;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.chk-circle > label{
  cursor:pointer;
  margin:0 10px  auto;
  
 }
.chk-hide {
  visibility: hidden;
}
.chk-circle > input[type=checkbox]:checked + i{
  border:3px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="chk-circle">
   <label for="chk1">some 1</label>
  <input class="chk-hide" type="checkbox" id="chk1"/>
<i></i>
</div>
<div class="chk-circle">
   <label for="chk2">some 2</label>
  <input class="chk-hide" type="checkbox" id="chk2"/>
<i></i>
</div>
<div class="chk-circle">
   <label for="chk3">some 3</label>
  <input class="chk-hide" type="checkbox" id="chk3"/>
<i></i>
</div>
```

Comment: would be nice if you add some text to the label, or make a bigger bullet, since it is hard to click on it

Answer (score 0):

Try `border-color` property:

```
.chk-circle input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #0f0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
div {
    background: pink;
    width: 50px;
    height:50px;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked+div{
  background: green;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked + div p {
    background: blue;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" checked>
<div>
   <p>Test</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you can change the structure of your html:

```
<input class="chk-hide" type="checkbox" id="chk1"/>
<div class="chk-circle">
 <label for="chk1"></label>
</div>
```

you can do it like this:

```
.chk-hide[type=checkbox]:checked +.chk-circle {background: green;}
```

[Example](http://codepen.io/desig9stein/pen/eBYGEW)